# stuck at the WHERE clauses to retrieve related results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/853da/5)

I have a few tables to store people's created polls in their threads. All poll options are products from another table. I'd like to know how to use a `product_id` to retrieve the polls and the poll options that have `Product A` as an option.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pr.product_name) AS product_name,
     GROUP_CONCAT(pr.img) AS img,v.poll_id
FROM vote_option v 
INNER JOIN poll p ON p.poll_id = v.poll_id
INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.product_id = v.product_id
GROUP BY poll_id
WHERE  product_id IN (SELECT ???? WHERE product_id = 1)
```

The main problem is that I have no idea what where clause I should use to get the following output by using just the keyword `product_id 1`, which represents `Product A`:

```
PRODUCT_NAME                               IMG                     POLL_ID
Product B,Product A,Product C              imgB,imgA,imgC          1
Product D,Product B,Product A,Product B    imgD,imgB,imgA,imgB     2
```

Table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE poll
    (`poll_id` int,`title`varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO poll
    (`poll_id`,`title`)
VALUES
    (1,'Title A'),
    (2,'Title B'),
    (3,'Title C')

;

CREATE TABLE vote_option
    (`poll_id` int,`product_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO vote_option
    (`poll_id`,`product_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,1),
    (2,2),
    (2,4),
    (2,2),
    (3,4),
    (3,5)

;

CREATE TABLE product
    (`product_id` int,`product_name` varchar(30),`img`varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO product
    (`product_id`,`product_name`,`img`)
VALUES
    (1,'Product A','imgA'),
    (2,'Product B','imgB'),
    (3,'Product C','imgC'),
    (4,'Product D','imgD'),
    (5,'Product E','imgE')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` with `SUM` to check product 1 must exist

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pr.product_name) AS product_name,
     GROUP_CONCAT(pr.img) AS img,v.poll_id
FROM vote_option v 
INNER JOIN poll p ON p.poll_id = v.poll_id
INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.product_id = v.product_id
GROUP BY v.poll_id
HAVING SUM(pr.product_id = 1) > 0
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/853da/6)

[or with product name](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/853da/10) `HAVING SUM(pr.product_name = 'Product A') > 0`